# send total sum to cross tab stimulsoft report

Tags: sum, report, crosstab, manual, stimulsoft

I have a Cross-Tab report in Stimul-Soft Reports.
In Data Grouping process, if I have more than one Grouping parameter (raw), there's error in the total sum of columns.

So I want to send the total sum of each columns to the report.
Please help me about this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: What version of Stimulsoft Reports do you use?

Comment: Stimulsoft Reports.Net
Version 2012.2.1304 from 4 May 2012

Comment: At first you should upgrade to the latest release. There was a lot of improvements.